# Inequality with the characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory, analysis

We know that $X$ has density function $f_X(x)=|x|^{-3} \mathbb{1}_{|x|\geq1}$

Let $\phi_X(t)$ be the characteristic function of the random variable. We need to show that for every $t \in [-1,1]$ the following equality holds:
$$|\phi_X(t)-1-t^2 \log|t|| \leq 3t^2$$

My attempt up to here:

We know that $X$ has a symmetric distribution, so the characteristic function is a real number for every $t$.
so
\begin{align*}
1-\phi_X(t)
=1- \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{itx} f(x)dx =1-\int_{\mathbb{R}} \cos(tx) f(x)dx= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx-\int_{\mathbb{R}} \cos(tx) f(x)dx
=2\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(tx)}{x^3} \stackrel{y=|t|x}{=} 2|t|^2 \int_{|t|}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos y}{y^3} dy 
\end{align*}
I've tried saying that
$$\int_{|t|}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos y}{y^3} dy \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos y}{y^3} dy $$
since the integrand is positive and then breaking the integral in two intervals: $[0,\epsilon] , [\epsilon,\infty)$ and use the fact that $1-\cos(y) \sim y^2/2$ when $y\to0$ and the fact that $|1-\cos(y)|$ is bounded by 2 at the second interval.

I've got nothing though, and i have no clue what to do even with the $t^2|log|t||$